# Check the lcd.begin() has been call or not

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

Is the any way to write a code to check whether lcd.begin has been called or not?

I am imagine something like this:

```
if (! (lcd.begin();)) { lcd.begin; }
else {}
```

I tried the above with no success...any suggestion?? Pls.

Comment: you're the one calling it so you should know if you called it or not right? what is the purpose of this?

Comment: because sometimes I cut off the power to the lcd by digitalWrite, so I need to recall it  if it is not called.

Comment: but if you're the one who cuts the power you know that you have to call it again.

Comment: if `lcd.begin();` helps at all in this case... BTW: You should rather think about (and edit your question) detecting if the lcd (or whatever) had been off-power while your arduino was running.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
// Add to your globals section.
int have_inited_lcd = 0;

// In the section, you call the lcd.begin do:
if (!have_inited_lcd) {
    have_inited_lcd = 1;
    lcd.begin();
}
```